# SQLAlchemy, InstrumentedAttribute, Column, Attribute

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Suppose I have a Column definition like this in my SQLAlchemy model:

`value = Column(String(500, collation="utf8mb4_unicode_ci"), nullable=False)`

I need to obtain the value of "collation".

I have an instance of InstrumentedAttribute (for that column) in my method.

How to navigate to that information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value.type.collation`

```py
value = Column(String(500, collation="utf8mb4_unicode_ci"), nullable=False)
print(value.type.collation)
# utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```